# How can this function be fixed?

Tags: javascript

I'm an absolute noob who has barely started learning JS, still working out how to use functions. This is a section of my first project (idle game) I just started working on:

```
function WneededDetermine(Lvl, needed, upgradecost, neededArr, costsArr, mainPower, secondaryPower, multi, lowerMainPower, lowerSecondaryPower, lowerMulti){
     switch (true) {
        case Lvl >= 15:
            needed = 250 * (Lvl - 10);
            upgradecost = costsArr[6]*Math.pow(mainPower, Lvl - 14) + multi*(secondaryPower, Lvl - 15);
            break;
        case Lvl >= 6:
             needed = 100 * (Lvl - 4);
             upgradecost = (costsArr[5]*Math.pow(lowerPower, Lvl - 5) + lowerMulti*Math.pow(lowerSecondaryPower, Lvl - 6)).toExponential(3);
             break;
        default:
             needed = neededArr[WLvl];
             upgradecost = costsArr[WLvl];
             break;
        return needed;

  };
};
```

And then

```
setInterval(function(){
   var Wneeded = WneededDetermine(WLvl, Wneeded, Wupgradecost, WupgradeLvlarr, Wupgradecosts, 30, 35, 5e13, 8, 12, 100000);
}, 10);
```

However the values Wneeded and Wupgradecost (which this is supposed to change) aren't changing. What did I do wrong? Am I completely off the mark as to how to use functions?

Edit: Removed the two return functions.

Comment: You can't return 2 values and you aren't changing variables.

Comment: How is this supposed to change those values?  Your function is trying to return two different things, which makes no sense, and the code which calls the function doesn't do anything with the returned value.

Comment: In Javascript, arguments are not passed by reference.

Comment: Your latest edit returns `Wneeded` which is undefined in that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so first of all, once you call "return" the function is done. Everything after "return ..." won't be executed so 2 return-statements at the end don't make any sense. The next big problem is, that you are calling the function which returns something, but you are not saving the result. 
You have to assign the function to a variable, so the values that are being returned are actually saved.

One way of fixing this is to return an array/list:

```
return [needed, upgradecost];
```

This way you only return once. Now you have to save the values from the array:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var returnData = WneededDetermine(WLvl, Wneeded, Wupgradecost, WupgradeLvlarr, Wupgradecosts, 30, 35, 5e13, 8, 12, 100000);
    needed = returnData[0];
    upgradecost = returnData[1];
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks! However when I put this in it shows that returnData is undefined so I can't get the values.

Comment: Are you sure you put that return-statement in the right place? And only 1 "return" this time? In theory it should work, here is a simplified, working version: https://repl.it/Ng4G/0

Answer (score -3):

Okay...so first you need to get rid of that switch clause, it's a wrong use of it, you should use an if-elseif-else structure:

```
    if(Lvl >= 15){
    ...
    }
    else if(Lvl >= 6){
    ...
    }
    else{
    ...
    }
```

Doing this, you have a better idea of the conditions for each upgradeCost and it will execute only one block of code depending on the level, as it happened with your swtich.

In addition to that, the problem is that when return is executed, the function gives its output to the main program,so the 2nd return will not be executed, so instead you should return an array.

```
     return[needed,upgradeCost];
```

DOn't forget to use camelCase (when you have two or more words as a variable name begin all of them unless the first one with a capital letter) for your variables as I just did, it would give your code way more clarity.

Good luck with that game!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `switch`. The [documentation of the `switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) explains how it is evaluated and the way it is used in the question is perfectly valid. Even more, the same documentation page provides an example similar to the one used here.

Comment: @axiac you are absolutely right, is a valid use of the switch clause, but that doesn't mean it should be used like that, in the same way that you could finish a while loop with a break but you shouldn't.
switch is intended for checking specific values that the expression could have rather than conditions other variables (not contained on the expression) have.